# Node JS Security Camera Motion Detection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node js module that emits events when motion is detected from my security camera. Even with the sensitivity settings set to low on the camera I am still getting motion events when there is no one there (Ex. wind blows leaves past camera).

The eventEmitter tells me when there is motion and when the motion ended. I wanted to see how I could go about triggering an event when there is motion for more than, say 3 seconds.

```
camera.on('alarm', function(code,action,index) {
  if (code === 'VideoMotion' && action === 'Start')
    //LOGIC: If action = start and for the next 3-5s action <> Stop
    console.log('Video Motion Detected')
  if (code === 'VideoMotion' && action === 'Stop')
    //Reset Timer   
    console.log('Video Motion Ended')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  let running;

 camera.on('alarm', function(code,action,index) {
    if (code === 'VideoMotion' && action === 'Start') {
      if(running) clearTimeout(running);
      running = setTimeout(trigger, 3000);
    }
    if (code === 'VideoMotion' && action === 'Stop' && running)
      clearTimeout(running);
 });

 function trigger(){
   //...
 }
```